# The best way to extract text from common documents formats (primarily rtf, doc, docx, pdf, epub, mobi) that works with UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp, .net-4.5, document, windows-10-universal

I'd like to implement support for these types of files in my application, but for this I need something that will let me extract raw text from these filetypes.

I'm looking for either a solution that doesn't require any additional libraries, or an all-in-one library/NuGet package. I took a look at `GemBox.Document` but it doesn't seem to be working with UWP projects.

What would be the best option for this?

Answer (score 1):

> I'm looking for either a solution that doesn't require any additional libraries, or an all-in-one library/NuGet package.

There is no such package.

In the standard UWP app we can read .rtf file with the [Rich edit box](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/rich-edit-box), there is code sample in this document shows how to edit, load, and save a Rich Text Format (.rtf) file in a `RichEditBox`.

For .doc, .docx, aka. MS Word document, especially the version after 2007, it uses Open-XML-SDK and currently it doesn't support UWP platform.

For .pdf documents, you can refer to @Franklin Chen's thread: [[UWP]PDF Viewing on a Windows Universal App](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/729dd0f5-3e33-46e9-b21f-0e08ecffbb58/uwppdf-viewing-on-a-windows-universal-app?forum=wpdevelop).

For epub files, it is a ZIP archive file, to parse this file, you can refer to the thread: [[WP8.1][C#] How can i read an EPub file in c# on Windows Phone!?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/c7394fec-d427-4e08-840e-939dab652485/wp81c-how-can-i-read-an-epub-file-in-c-on-windows-phone?forum=wpdevelop).

For mobi files, sorry I couldn't find any useful information for development for the moment, I can only now suggest to convert it to pdf file with free online service.

But in a word, since Open-XML-SDK currently doesn't support UWP platform. It is not possible to find a solution or package for standard UWP app. You can try to find such a web service and implement this service in your app, or you can use commercial libraries which can read documents in all these formats.